# JPA @ManyToMany relationship and Eclipse Link

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

In Eclipse link I'am getting such error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: pl.salonea.entities.Education@9a07c360
```

while persisting @ManyToMany relationship in database.

```
 // wire up both Employee and Education entities
            employee1.getEducations().add(santaClaraUniversity);
            employee1.getEducations().add(stanfordUniversity);
            employee2.getEducations().add(massachusettsInstituteOfTechnology);
            employee3.getEducations().add(massachusettsInstituteOfTechnology);

            santaClaraUniversity.getEducatedEmployees().add(employee1);
            stanfordUniversity.getEducatedEmployees().add(employee1);
            massachusettsInstituteOfTechnology.getEducatedEmployees().add(employee2);
            massachusettsInstituteOfTechnology.getEducatedEmployees().add(employee3);

            // persist employees and educations in database
            employeeFacade.create(employee1);
            employeeFacade.create(employee2);
            employeeFacade.create(employee3);

            educationFacade.create(stanfordUniversity);
            educationFacade.create(santaClaraUniversity);
            educationFacade.create(massachusettsInstituteOfTechnology);
```

The error is thrown on first line of **employeeFacade.create(employee1);**

This code works perfectly well in Hibernate and in EclipseLink there is such problem. I try to add CascadeType.PERSIST but don't know why in Hibernate it works, and why in EclipseLink it doesn't.

I am a little confused how to persist @OneToMany, @ManyToOne relationships properly? Should I always set both sides of relationship and then persist entities on both sides? Should I persist as here in separate transactions or should i wrap it in UserTransaction? (as this is JTA + Arquillian)

**UPDATE 1**
After adding on both sides CascadeTyp.PERSIST above code throws such error

```
   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Bachelor of Computer Science-Stanford University' for key 'UNQ_education_0'
Error Code: 1062
```

On line educationFacade.create(santaClaraUniversity);

**UPDATE 2** 
After wrapping above facade.create() code in **utx.begin()** and **utx.commit()** it seems to persist entities but than is another problem with deletion like below

```
 assertTrue(educationFacade.deleteByEmployee(employee1) == 2);
```

and this method is implemented as:

```
@Override
public Integer deleteByEmployee(Employee employee) {

    // select educations for given employee that will be deleted in the following query
    List<Education> educations = findByEmployee(employee);

    return deleteByEducations(educations);
}

@Override
public Integer deleteByEducations(List<Education> educations) {

    Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(Education.DELETE_BY_EDUCATIONS);
    query.setParameter("educations", educations);
    return query.executeUpdate();
}
```

and i have named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = Education.DELETE_BY_EDUCATIONS, query = "DELETE FROM Education e WHERE e IN :educations")
```

In hibernate this bulk delete of Educations by Employees works correctly:

[image: in hibernate it works but in eclipse link not]

It even deleted correctly association in database in spite of the fact that Education is just inversion side...

[image]

And in **EclipseLink** there is 0 rows deleted, I suppose there is some constraint-related problem (i.e. many to many association can not be deleted?) Education is inverse side of relation (with mappedBy element) and Employee is the owning side

**UPDATE 3**
I have added such code in deleteByEducations methdod (Education entities):

```
for(Education edu : educations) {
        for(Employee empl :edu.getEducatedEmployees()) {
            empl.getEducations().remove(edu);
            getEntityManager().merge(empl);
        }
    }
```

In database in join table (for ManyToMany relationship) records associated with this educations (that I want to delete) has been removed. But Education entity hasn't been deleted continuously. Maybe there is something with this named query above?:

```
DELETE FROM Education e WHERE e IN :educations
```

**UPDATE 4**
Implementing deleteByEducations() method this way works correctly so there can be something with named queries maybe such construct isn't compatible with EclipseLink (but have worked in Hibernate). 
But this new solution is rather cumbersome.

```
@Override
    public Integer deleteByEducations(List<Education> educations) {

        Integer deletedCount = 0;

        for(Education edu : educations) {
            for(Employee empl :edu.getEducatedEmployees()) {
                empl.getEducations().remove(edu);
                getEntityManager().merge(empl);
            }

            Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(Education.DELETE_BY_EDUCATION);
            query.setParameter("education", edu);
            deletedCount += query.executeUpdate();
        }

        return deletedCount;
    }
```

**UPDATE 5** 
Moreover this solution without removing association records from join table also works correctly.

```
@Override
    public Integer deleteByEducations(List<Education> educations) {

        Integer deletedCount = 0;

        for(Education edu : educations) {

            Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(Education.DELETE_BY_EDUCATION);
            query.setParameter("education", edu);
            deletedCount += query.executeUpdate();
        }

        return deletedCount;
    }
```

Comment: Have you added the correct PERSIST option, viz. javax.persistence.CascadeType.PERSIST and not org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST?

Comment: yes I have then this second error about duplicates... I have tried now to use utx.begin(), utx.commit() in order to wrap this create statements and seems to persist but then i problem with deleting persisted Entities

Comment: And what is wrong with 'assertTrue(educationFacade.deleteByEmployee(employee1) == 2);'?

Comment: I have this NamedQuery defined to delete educations by employees in hibernate seems to work correctly but now it doesn't work in EclipeLink. I consider whether if I have such bulk DELETE FROM I also should manually remove ManyToMany association from join table? Education has been inverse side and Employee owning side but after I have changed there is still error!

Comment: Take a step back and work on one problem at a time.  Your first issue is that you are making changes to a detached entity, creating a new entity to reference it, then calling persist.  You are not allowed to call persist on a detached entity - JPA will throw an exception if it detects it, or just try to reinsert the entity which too should result in an exception.  Try merging your changed, detached entity and have its references to the new entity marked with cascade merge.  Or use the managed instance to both make changes and be used in the reference for the new entity.

Comment: For the second problem/update, you are missing a lot of details that are important.  What is returned from findByEmployee, and what SQL is used for the executeUpdate query?  Make sure that you are in fact modifying both sides of your bidirectional relationships if you plan to use them later on, as they remain in the cache, which is handled differently by different providers.  If you don't maintain it, you can't trust it is accurate later on unless you force a refresh.

Comment: Yeah but now when Im using UserTransaction entities are persisted and linked with ManyToMany association, the current error is in place when I'm trying to remove this entities using bulk delete "DELETE FROM" the same code works in hibernate but doesn't work in EclipseLink. Method findByEmployee(employee); finds proper Education entities to delete in Education.DELETE_BY_EDUCATIONS named query but they don't get deleted just error is thrown

Comment: Maybe before I execute Education.DELETE_BY_EDUCATIONS, I should remove binding to this Education entities in Employee entities ?

Comment: You've jumped around too much for this post to be easy to follow.  Pick one issue and lets debug it, not try to solve all the issues in all your different attempts.   There is nothing wrong with named queries in EclipseLink - they work.  You did not say your query gets an error - what is the error?  You flipped between asking about a ManyToMany and then OnetoMany/ManyToOne relationship - what exactly is giving you the problem here?   For the delete all query, what is the SQL used and what exactly are you passing in?

Comment: Seems that such named query throws exception in EclipseLink but works in Hibernate: DELETE FROM Education e WHERE e IN :educations